# What happens to jquery event handlers after element removal?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I register an jquery event handler on a DIV - what happens after the removal of the DIV? If I do this regularly (single page app) - will I run into memory leaks?

HTML:

```
<div id="elm12345"></div>
```

JS:

```
$('#elm12345').on(...);
...
$('#elm12345').remove();
```

Do I have to remove the event handler manually?

Comment: I doubt otherwise it was already fixed in jQuery community.

Comment: If you use jQuery to remove the element, any associated data and event handlers will be removed beforehand to prevent memory leaks.

Comment: not with the way jQuery adds events. event handler leaks were mostly a problem in ie6 and with certain kinds of binding in ie7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the jQuery documentation for `.remove()`:

> Similar to `.empty()`, the `.remove()` method takes elements out of the DOM. Use .remove() when you want to remove the element itself, as well as everything inside it. **In addition to the elements themselves, all bound events and jQuery data associated with the elements are removed.** To remove the elements without removing data and events, use .detach() instead.

**Reference:** [`.remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)

I've highlighted the part of the passage that answers your question. You can find this passage on the linked reference page, first paragraph.